# Deciding which eigenvalues I should choose

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Find the harmonic function $u(x, y)$ in the square $D = {0 < x < π, 0 < y
> < π}$
>
> with the boundary conditions:
>
> $$\begin{align} u_y & = 0 \quad \text{ for } y = 0 \text{ for } y = \pi, \\ u & = 0 \quad \text{ for } x = 0, \end{align}$$
>
> and
>   $$u = \cos^2 y = \frac 1 2(1 + \cos (2y)) \text{ for } x= \pi.$$

When I do separation of variables I don't know which eigenvalue I should choose:

Here,

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$$

$$ \frac {X''} X= -\frac {Y''} Y$$

now I should decide whether   (assuming $\lambda \geq 0$)

$$ \frac {X''} X= -\frac {Y''} Y=\lambda $$

or, $$ \frac {X''} X= -\frac {Y''} Y= -\lambda $$

So that I can proceed whether

$$ X(x)=A_1\cos \beta x A_2\sin\beta x$$

or$$ X(x)=A_1\cosh \beta x A_2\sinh\beta x$$
where $\beta^2=\lambda\quad $and $A_1, A_2\quad$ are constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if

$$Y^{\prime\prime}=\pm\lambda Y$$

then

$$Y=\begin{cases}A\cosh\big(\sqrt{\lambda} y\big)+B\sinh\big( \sqrt{\lambda}y\big),&+\lambda\\A\cos\big(\sqrt{\lambda} y\big)+B\sin\big(\sqrt{\lambda} y\big),&-\lambda&\end{cases}$$

You need $Y^{\prime}$ to vanish on **both** $y=0$ and $y=\pi$, and thus you must have $-\lambda$ to allow this.

Comment: So you mean I have to make sure that boundary conditions for both X(x) and Y(y) are satisfied for the eigenvalue I chose, if not I should change it?

Answer (score 1):

Your first boundary condition $u_y=0$ for $y=0$ and $y=\pi$ when inputted into the the ansatz you make for the solution implies $$X(x)Y'(0)=0,$$ and $$X(x)Y'(\pi)=0,$$ that is $$Y'(0)=Y'(\pi)=0.$$ This means you need some sort of periodicity in your solution which implies it has to be of a trigonometric form which is only obtained when $\lambda<0.$

Comment: You meant $Y'$ I guess

Comment: Yes edited, apologies.